# Download file is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I am having a page, which contains an `iframe`.

The source for the iframe is not from the same domain.

The parent URL is: `xyz.com`, the iframe URL is: `abc.com`

The iFrame contains a download button, that downloads files. This download button works fine in Chrome but its not working IE

`xyz.com` page content.

```
<html>
  <body>
     <iFrame src="abc.com"></iFrame>
  </body>
<html>
```

`abc.com` page

```
<button onClick ="downloadFile()">Download</button>

function downloadFile()
{
   window.location = "abc.com/download";
}
```